# PSExec run remote batch file

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop, psexec

I wanna run remote a batch file with PSExec, so my code looks like this:

```
cd C:\PsTools
PsExec.exe \\<computer> -u <user> -p <password> -s -i <"pathToBatchFile\batch.bat">  
exit
```

After I call the batch file on the remote computer, the application on the remote computer is starting under the SYSTEM account. I wanna start it under another account.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You should not use the `-s` switch.

From the [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553):

> -s    Run remote process in the System account.

Comment: I have try to run it without the -s parameter, but if I do so, my application not even starts.

Comment: My .log file looks like this, if I don't use the -s parameter

> ERROR: Login failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Comment: @user846290 That's a completely different issue to your question. I suggest you raise another question to get this answered. However, you should verify that the user-credentials you are passing to PSExec will allow you to login to that PC...